# I want charts to preserve formatting when I chnge data

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

Suppose I want to make multiple similar charts within a single workbook. The only difference among the charts is the variables to plot. I can set up a range of multiple chart sheets and change the variable as needed, but the problem is that the data is complex enough that I had to impose manual color selections. When I change the data inputs, the charts revert to pre-manual selections. How do I force Excel to maintain the specific colors I chose but just pour in the new data? I am using Excel 2016 on Windows.

Comment: Have you tried using a chart style?